# SQLAlchemy Add Many to One row logic

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have this table structure in SQLAlchemy:

```
User(Base)
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user")

Address(Base)
    __talbename__ = 'addresses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(users.id))
```

So a Many (addresses) to One (user) relationship.

My question is now how can I easily add a an address to a user without deleting the addresses already stored.

In pure SQL I would just insert a row in the address table with a foreign key to the right user.

This is how I'm doing it right now in SQLAlchemy (method in User Class):

```
def add_address(self, address):
    adds = self.addresses
    adds.append(address)
    self.addresses = adds
```

So What I'm basically doing is first finding all the addresses, then appending the list to overwrite the list again with the extra address.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define another relationship between User and Address, which will not be loaded using `lazy='noload'` (see [Setting Noload](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/collections.html#setting-noload)):

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user")
    addresses_noload = relationship("Address", lazy='noload')

    def add_address(self, address):
        adds = self.addresses_noload # @note: use the relationship which does not load items from DB
        adds.append(address)
```

*Also see [sqlalchemy add child in one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8839211/99594) for similar question.*